# Spark sql queries on partitioned table with removed partitions files fails

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

Below is what am trying in order,

1. create partitioned table in hive based on current hour.
2. use spark hive context and perform msck repair table.
3. delete the hdfs folders of one of the added partitions manually.
4. use spark hive context again and perform
   a> msck repair
     this does not remove the partition added already with no hdfs folder.
     seems like known behavior with respect to "msck repair"
   b> select * from tablexxx where (existing partition);
     Fails with exception : Filenotfound exception pointing to hdfs folder 
     which was deleted manually.

Any insights on this behavior would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` will only discover new partitions, not delete "old" ones.

Working with external hive tables where you deleted the HDFS folder, I see two solutions

1. drop the table (files will not be deleted because the table is external), then re-create the table using the same location, and then run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`. This is my prefered solution.
2. Drop all the partitions you deleted using  `ALTER TABLE <table> DROP PARTITION <partition>`

What you observe in your case is maybe related to these: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15044 and 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19187

Comment: Thanks for the approaches on partitions repair. But my concern here is why spark sql throws exception even though, am not using the deleted partition in the query which am running ? the query is run on a partition where the hdfs are not deleted. it still scans and throws exception for partition where hdfs files are deleted but  not used in the query.

Comment: I could imagine this is because spark reads metadata (not actual data) of all partitions

Comment: note that there is also a jira open for this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15044